# Why does my rsync script do a full backup everytime?

Tags: macos, backup, rsync

I have the following rsync script which I created to do incremental backups:

```
rsync -arv --exclude-from '/usr/bin/exclude-list.txt' --delete /Volumes/DOCS/ /Volumes/BKUP1/DOCS/ 
&& rsync -arv --delete /Volumes/Webserver/ /Volumes/BKUP1/Webserver/
```

My exclude list is

```
/Volumes/Webserver/.Spotlight-V100
/Volumes/Webserver/.Trashes
/Volumes/Webserver/.fseventsd
```

Everytime I run this backup. It seems to go through and copy all the files everytime, despite the fact that rsync is supposed to be an incremental backup solution.

E.G. First run:

```
....
sites/website/sites/all/libraries/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/style/js/.svn/prop-base/
sites/website/sites/all/libraries/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/style/js/.svn/props/
sites/website/sites/all/libraries/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/style/js/.svn/text-base/
....
```

Second run:

```
....
sites/website/sites/all/libraries/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/style/js/.svn/prop-base/
sites/website/sites/all/libraries/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/style/js/.svn/props/
sites/website/sites/all/libraries/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/style/js/.svn/text-base/
....
etc...
```

The same files are copied across again. Also I am constantly encountering the following permission denied errors, despite the fact they are ignored in my excude-from argument:

```
building file list ... rsync: opendir "/Volumes/Webserver/.Spotlight-V100" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: opendir "/Volumes/Webserver/.Trashes" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: opendir "/Volumes/Webserver/.fseventsd" failed: Permission denied (13)
```

Any ideas? I am hoping I can tweak this script so it will only copy across modified / new files and show me what files these are in the verbose output.

Many thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

I ran in to this myself. The best I could come up with, as silly as this sounds, is that the files' timestamps aren't being preserved. Then when you do it again it thinks "Hey! These timestamps don't match - better sync 'em!" If you use the -t option, It will send the timestamps along, then the files will be seen as the same

Or you can use the "size only" option, which does what it sounds, if you're sure there are no files you've modified but are the same size.

Answer (score 1):

Are you copying to a FAT32 drive from a differently formatted drive? My understanding is that FAT32 keeps a 16-bit time-stamp which only permits a resolution of about two seconds, which is far less precise than other drive formats. By default, rsync requires timestamps to match exactly, so virtually every file will fail this test and be recopied.

To fix this, you need to have rsync to pass files that are time-stamped +/-1 second (2 second total range) from the source. You do this by adding

```
--modify-window=1
```

to the rsync command.